# Python Syntax Incorrect

Tags: python, mod-python

I am a novice with Python. I am trying to output a first initial last name for an email address. Such as:

John Doe
jdoe@domain.com

I am using the following Python:

```
primary_mail = '%(givenname)s'[0:1]%(surname)s@%(domain)s
```

But when it outputs I don't get:

```
jdoe@domain.com
```

Instead I get some jumbled thing:

```
params = { "givenname":"Hans", "surname":"Wurst", "domain":"fleischer" }
print "'%(givenname)s'[0:1]%(surname)s@%(domain)s" % params
```

Can someone help me? I don't understand Python 100% yet so sorry if this is very novice.

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to do and what variables your have. 

Try standard 2.7 syntax:
my_string = "%s@%s" % (username, domain)

Comment: Hi! I simply want first initial of the "givenname" and combine it with the last name, which is "surname" and add the domain after that. Does that make sense?

Comment: This isn't about **Managing** systems in an business environment and as such is off topic. It may be more approprite for [so] but check their about and faq pages.

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Combine each part with the + operator:

```
>>> params['givenname'][0].lower() + params['surname'].lower() + '@' + params['domain']
'hwurst@fleischer'
```

Comment: Thank you!! So for my primary_mail ... I would put this in?

Answer (score 0):

For python2.7 it would look like this:

```
>>> name = "ivan"
>>> lastname = "bobrov"
>>> my_email = "%s@%s" % (name[0:1], lastname)
>>> print my_email
i@bobrov
>>>
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: So for my primary_mail this is what I'd put.. What you have for my_email?